# How do I display XML that has been posted to an ASHX handler on a page?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, ashx

I am a new programmer working with C# and building a simple page, to which a third-party service posts XML. I would like to simply display this XML as text on a webpage.

I've started a new ASHX file that contains the following method:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);

    String xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.LoadXml(xmlData);

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    context.Response.Write(xmlData);

}
```

However, when the third-party application tries to post to the page, I get an error that the Root Element is missing.

If I understand this error correctly, this would seem to imply that the XML that was posted is not formatted correctly.

1.) If I am incorrect in this assumption, is there something wrong with the way that I am trying to receive and display the XML data using this handler?

2.) Otherwise, how might I easily troubleshoot by examining the contents of the XML that is sent to the service using my handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) It's a good assumption, or the request is blank.

The `doc.LoadXml(xmlData);` line will be where it's complaining about about a missing root element.

2.) You could start by simply commenting out the above line, because you're not doing anything with the `doc` object yet.

You might also need to set the content type to `text/plain`

Longer term, you may want some try/catch logic around the `LoadXml()` call. Something like this perhaps...

```
try
{
    doc.LoadXml(xmlData);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    context.Response.Write(xmlData);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(e.Message);
}
```